# Understanding the quantum state of light

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have trouble understanding what the quantum state of light represents.

For a particle, its state can be represented by an element of L^2, which can be seen as the superposition coefficients along all possible positions. Probabilities follow by multiplying by the conjugate.

For a qubit, its state can be represended by C^2, which can be seen as the superposition coefficients on theZspin. Spin measurement probabilities along any direction arethus given simply by projecting along the right orthonormal basis

But for light, I don't understand which Hilbert space we are talking about and what it represents, calculations start by definining ladder oeprators, quadrature operators etc without the underlying space. Although I think I understand their meaning for a quantum harmonic oscillator, I can't see the analogy with light since we are not talking about a particle evolving with the same Hamiltonian